# Непонятная надпись на странице собственного профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, профиль-участника, мобильная-версия

К чему относится слово "подписки" в мобильной версии? При попытке кликнуть по нему активируется пункт "Настройки". Дефект обнаружен в браузере Google Chrome 63.0.3239.107

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Телефон повернуть в альбомную ориентацию не пробовал?

Comment: @Qwertiy при альбомной ориентации выглядит посимпатичнее

Comment: Где-то недавно это обсуждали уже.

Comment: @alexolut может быть и такое. Я только вчера вечером заметил эту особенность.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я добавил неразрывный пробел во фразу "Настройки подписки". У меня теперь отображается адекватно:

> [image: настройки подписки]

Проверьте на вашем устройстве.